# Re-enabling backspace as "go back" in recent Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, backspace

Since start of this summer, I think that Google removed the option of using backspace for returning to previous page or so.

I was wondering, if there exist any chance, of undo-ing this thing? Is there such thing that would help me, such as downgrading Chrome or using any additional add-ons or something such as this for getting this glorious function back?

It's nearly impossible for me to forget this shortcut (as old habits die hard, lol) and keep pressing it and later on using the mouse to go back.